remote return url have not encoded values gives 403 error
I have external api and i dont change return url and return url have special characters and when return url works gives 403 url. I dont change return url so comes from remote.
Im using php and my hosting cpanel.
my return url under below.
https://www.mywebsite.com/folder/?fail=true&order_no=&order_id=&invoice_id=59448&status_code=1&status_description=cc+no+istenilen+formatta+değil.&transaction_type=Auth&1&error_code=1&error=cc+no+istenilen+formatta+değil.&auth_code=&installment=1

how can i fix this ?  any idea ?
error and status_description parametres have special characters
I dont change return url so comes from remote.

What exactly is causing the 403 error on your end? Does it happen on the web server level already, due to some sort of firewall rules? Or does your actual PHP script behind this deliberately respond with a 403, because it doesn't like the parameters?

@CBroe return url this coming from remote i didnt change it with php codes maybe .htaccess will replace or somethings i think in url have error and status_description parameters have special characters and + like characters so gives bad url 403 error need to replace that params or need url encoded that values i think.. finally this url comes from remote gives 403 Forbidden s to this resource on the server is denied! page

The + characters are just the URL encoding of a space character. And pretty much the only "special" character I can spot that could be problematic, is the ğ - that should rather have been properly encoded as %C4%9F. If your server rejects the URL because of this, then you'll need to go and look into your configuration/setup. Checking if the error log has anything to say about the cause of the 403 error, would be a good start.

@CBroe yes problem this im using cpanel where can i fix it ? ty

The http server writes an error log file. That usually is the first place to start looking. How you can access that file depends on your hosting service, we cannot say. Much easier certainly would be to start debugging in your local development environment where you have full access to all that.
